# NullPointerException while accessing Servlet Response from Java

Tags: java

I am calling  a Java servlet from my Java file. The servlet file has SOP to return a JSON string. Now I wish to use that string in my Java code and then parse it into XML.

My code is as follows:

```
URL urlS = new URL (servletURL);
URLConnection urlc;
urlc = urlS.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("We got JSON Buddy: "+inputLine);
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(inputLine);
System.out.println("We got json object js: "+js.toString());
in.close();
```

The problem is my SOP for Java code is :

```
12-02 10:30:12.254: I/System.out(24169): We got JSON Buddy: {"movies": { "total": 19, "movie":[{"cover":"http://content9.flixster.com/movie/11/16/04/11160419_pro.jpg","tile":"A Very Harold & Kumar 3D Christmas","MovieDuration":"(R , 1 hr. 29 min.)","showtime":"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           9:35 PM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         12:00 AM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ","theatre":"Rave Motion Pictures 18 + IMAX","url":"http://www.flixster.com/movie/a-very-harold-and-kumar-christmas"},{"cover":"http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/16/12/11161272_pro.jpg","tile":"Arthur Christmas 3D","MovieDuration":"(PG , 1 hr. 37 min.)","showtime":"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           12:15 PM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3:00 PM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         5:35 PM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ","theatre":"Rave Motion Pictures 18 + IMAX","url":"http://www.flixster.com/movie/arthur-christ
12-02 10:30:12.266: I/System.out(24169): Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The issue is I am not getting the complete output in the inputLine, and the other problem is the NullPointerException. I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: It's "Java", not "JAVA".

Comment: Oops!! Time to edit my Resume as well !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loop is doing this:

```
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("We got JSON Buddy: "+inputLine);
```

For the loop to terminate, `inputLine` has to be null so when you get here: `JSONObject js = new JSONObject(inputLine);`
you will get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Yeah.. strange inputLine still shows some data... shall i clean project for this ?

Comment: What do you mean, it "still shows some data?" Do you mean in the debugger? If you're just talking about the log statement, that is because the first time through the loop, inputLine isn't null so control enters the body and prints out the log statement. It isn't until the second iteration that it is set to null and then control exits the loop and continues to the next statement.

Comment: Yeah i was talking about the same .. Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1):

See if this is better:

```
        URL urlS = new URL (servletURL);
        URLConnection urlc;
        urlc = urlS.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("We got JSON Buddy: "+inputLine);
            JSONObject js = new JSONObject(inputLine);            
            System.out.println("We got json object js: "+js.toString());
        }
        in.close();
```

Comment: Sorry, but Isnt it the very same code of mine ? or i could not see the difference.

Comment: The difference is the braces around the block that you want to loop with `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you're doing here:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("We got JSON Buddy: "+inputLine);
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(inputLine);
```

You're keeping reading *until* `inputLine` is null. You're *then* calling:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(inputLine);
```

So your code is effectively:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("We got JSON Buddy: "+inputLine);
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(null);
```

Presumably that's the problem. So, the question is: where did you *want* to loop?

Comment: So the thing is Servlet responds me with a SOP that has my JSON string. But i am not able to get it here in a variable that i can decompose later into variables ....

Comment: @typedef1: What do you mean by "a SOP"? Anyway, I've explained what's going wrong here - as have others. How many lines are you actually expecting? If you're only expecting a single line, that would simplify things.

Comment: Sorry, I thought SOP is widely used for System.out.println

Comment: @typedef1: "log" would be more normal... especially as it then doesn't matter exactly how the information was logged. Anyway, how many lines are you expecting, and how do you want to handle multiple lines?

Comment: The JSON string returned by the servlet is a simple variable that is formed by concatenating different strings throughout the program to a variable JSONstr. So i just want the output of that JSONsstr in a variable.

Comment: @typedef1: So is it a single line? My point is that your original code has a loop in there, as if you were expecting multiple lines. Are you *actually* expecting multiple lines?